# What is neutrino pair exchange? Can neutrino pair exchange deduce stronger-than-electromagnetic attractive forces between electrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electrons, neutrinos

I read recently about neutrino pair exchange. What is neutrino pair exchange? Can this exchange induce forces stronger than electromagnetic forces between electrons which in turn form attractive electronic bodies?

Could someone here please explain for me? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think it will induce (not deduce) a stronger than EM force? Neutrinos are affected by gravity and the weak force, which are both weaker than the EM force.

Comment: Re “I recently read”: a link would be helpful.